# Python: Predicting vector from a scalar

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I am working on a problem where I have to predict a vector *y* from a scalar *x*. I am currently using linear regression to create a baseline model. But it does not seem to handle the multi-dimesional output.

I am using the following the code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()

lm.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

In this case, x_train is a column vector of shape *(1,m)* and y_train is a vector of vectors of shape *(m,)*.

The error message produced can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bBJR.png).

I think it has to do something with multi-output parameter. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I have worked on problems where input and output were both scalars. Logically speaking, a linear regression model should fit any problem, even if poorly. The problem here is handling the multi-dimensional output variable. @DamianSatterthwaite-Phillips

Comment: @Taimur-- misunderstood your problem on my first answer... reposted below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the data that you are using but try reshaping your "x_train" by using x_train.reshape(-1,1) and then fitting this reshaped data to your linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your underlying data look like, but the error message `bool object has no attribute 'any'`, suggests something wrong with the way your `y` object is formatted.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

N = 100
x = np.random.choice(range(3), size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': x,
    'y1': 3 * x + np.random.normal(size=N),
    'y2': -0.2 * x + np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=N),
    'y3': -x + 12 + np.random.normal(scale=0.3, size=N)})
print(df.head())

X = df.pop('x').to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, df)

preds = reg.predict(X)
print(preds[:5])
print('coefs:', reg.coef_)
print('intercepts:', reg.intercept_)
```